# Navigation Drawer Activity: passing values between fragment

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer

I have a problem, I can't pass a `String` value from a `Fragment` to another `Fragment`.

This is a part of my code:

The `FragmentA`:

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private HomeViewModel homeViewModel;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(HomeViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

    Button btn = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            GalleryFragment galleryFragment = new GalleryFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            String s = "ciao";
            bundle.putString("Data", s);
            galleryFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //with this i know the function is ok
        }
    });
    return root;
}
}
```

The `FragmentB`:

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

private GalleryViewModel galleryViewModel;
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    galleryViewModel =
            ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(GalleryViewModel.class);
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);

    Bundle bundle = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
    TextView textView = (TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.myTitleText);
    if(bundle!=null){
        String name = bundle.getString("Data");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),name,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        textView.setText(name);
    }
    return root;
}
}
```

If I delete the `if(bundle!=null)` part, the debugger give me this error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference`

SUMMARY:

I am on `fragmentA` --> I click the button --> I move to `fragmentB` to see if the `TextView` has changed value --> nothing happened.

Can someone explain me what is the error?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I want to specify that I tried many solutions found here on this platform and others but I don't why none of those solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the solution -_-, I dont know why before didnt work.

Inside of `FragmentA` in the `onClick` method, paste this at the end:

```
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, galleryFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            transaction.commit();
```

I post this for who need it

Answer (score 0):

You should look into ViewModel: [ViewModel Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#java).

You should initialize a ViewModel in your parent activity and then when each Fragment is created, provide access to that common ViewModel.

All 3 components will then have shared access to a common lifecycle-conscious object that you can use for easy intercommunication.